# Integrating C++ coverage with sonarqube

Tags: c++, sonarqube, teamcity, code-coverage, googletest

I am using Google test framework for C++ unit tests. We are building our projects using MsBuild (runs on teamcity). Now, I want sonarqube to parse the coverage info. We have cfamily plugin in sonarqube. The compatible reports with cfamily plugin are bullseye, vscoverage, gcov, llvm-cov. As per my knowledge, because we can't use gcc for compiling, llvm-cov and gcov are ruled out. Since we are using googletest and also wants to run this on teamcity, vscoverage isn't possible. We aren't using Bullseye. (It is more for functional automation I am told).

So I have decide to use OpenCppCoverage tool. This can generate coverage in cobertura format or generic format specified by sonarqube. I have tried generic format but sonarqube is ignoring the coverage for files but is parsing them successfully.

Exploring more, I tried to use C++ community plugin(cxx). But I wasn't able to disable cfamily plugin so that C++ community can be used.

So I want to know if I can do something else so that coverage of our C++ test projects can be parsed by sonarqube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the paths in coverage report generated by OpenCppCoverage using [OCCSonarQube plugin](https://github.com/virinchivarma/OCCSonarQube/tree/case-sensitivity). Now SonarQube is able to parse the report in generic format.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [sonar-cxx](https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx) plug-in from **SonarOpenCommunity**. This plugin adds C++ support to **SonarQube**. It's free plug-in and availble with LGPL-3.0 License.

Comment: yes, I have. The problem is we have  cfamily already installed. We have common server for others so, I just added cxx plugin. Even though I set suffixes for c++ invalid, sonar-scanner is failing, coverage report from cxx wasn't gathered. Also I think there are some issues with both these plugins co-existence.